# PostgreSQL Update Error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update rows for a table using this query:

```
UPDATE point 
SET ftp_base = ftp://ftp.geonet.org.nz/strong/processed/Proc/2007/02_Final/2001-02-04_191426/Vol3/data/20070204_191426_KFHS.v3a
WHERE evt_id = '1121';
```

It is giving me the error "syntax error at or near SET".

Answer (score 3):

`point` is a reserved word (a datatype). You need to enclose this in double quotes:

```
UPDATE "point"
   SET ftp_base = 'your value goes here'
WHERE evt_id = 1121
```

Don't forget the single quotes around the character values, and do not put them around numbers.